# On weekdays I catch a bus into Torquay to go to

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does it mean that their destination point is Torquay or it is the bus destination point but they can get off earlier to go to their classes?

> On weekdays I **catch a bus into Torquay** to go to language classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worded in that way it would certainly suggest to me that their language classes were in Torquay.

If the destination point was earlier than Torquay, I would say:

"On Wednesdays I catch the Torquay bus to get to my language classes (in Puddletown)."

Comment: So, there is no information about the bus final destination point, right? It could be Torquay or another town, right?

Comment: That's right, there's no information about the bus. Neither it's destination nor starting point are mentioned, nor any other information, such as the bus number, format, colour etc.

Comment: No. If you say "I catch a bus into Torquay" - it doesn't tell you anything further about the bus other than that it goes to Torquay.